# How to create jar file of my selenium Java project with JUnit & cucumber framework

Tags: java, selenium, junit

Could you please let me know the steps on how to create a jar file of my selenium Java project with JUnit & cucumber framework, So that it can be executable on a system with out installing Selenium/Eclipse.

I'm able to run the cucumber test scripts in eclipse successfully, however unable to locate the test cases when i go to export>java>javarunnable.jar file>click on next and could not find my test cases in Launch Configuration list.

Please suggest

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for the same, if you have the solution by now...please post the steps..thanks